# Fractional Knapsack : why value/weight?

Tags: algorithm, greedy

In Fractional Knapsack problem,

**1. prepare the third array, value per weight array, dividing the weight of each item by its corresponding value**

**2. sort the items in descending order according to their value per weight**

the reason behind the step 1 and 2?

Answer (score 0):

Because it is more profitable to fill all possible volume with substance having the highest value/weight ratio. So use up all given quantity of item with the best value/weight ratio, then with the second and so on.

Just think - if you believe that it is possible to fill some part with less valuable item (while more valuable  one is available) - change it to more valuable and you'll have got some additional money

Answer (score 0):

In fractional knapsack you can add part/fraction of item in your knapsack(answer) to maximize the total value of item in your bag. As the goal is to maximize the total value in knapsack we should put items such that the value of weight being put is high and it takes as less space as possible , so that more can be added to the knapsack. Hence, the weight per value is required to calculate. The capacity of knapsack is not unlimited , hence we need value per weight to utilize the space optimally.

For example if we have weight ={10,20,30,} and value {60,100,120} and bag can hold 50 at Max then if don't divide the item then we can have only 1 item of 20 and 1 of 30 . So the total value will be 220.

But as per fractional knapsack we divide value by weight and get the array {6,5,4} . Sort it(already sorted ) . Now the order of item becomes i1,i2, i3

`Take all 10 kg of i1=6*10
Take all 20kg of i2= 5*20
Take the remaining 20kg from  i3= 4*((2/3)*30)`

Total value is= 60+100+80= 240

Hence, we need value per weight.

Refer the link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fractional-knapsack-problem/

Answer (score 0):

This is related to basic mathematics. Let's take a constant, which has numerator and denominator.

In this case:

**Constant**: value/weight ratio.
**Numerator**: value
**Denominator**: weight

As the *Constant* and *Numerator* have direct relation, when the constant is bigger, the numerator is also bigger. Simultaneously, when the constant is bigger, the denominator is smaller, as they have indirect relation.

So, when we're arranging ratios in descending order, we're trying to sort entries of maximum value and less weight relatively and put them in our bag with given capacity in that order.

Answer (score 0):

Two main reasons for doing that in Fractional Knapsack Problem:

- Sorting items by value-to-weight ratio allows for a greedy approach, where you consider adding items to the knapsack in descending order of their value-to-weight ratio. This means you prioritize items that give you the most value for the least weight.
- You can add fractions of items, which makes it important to start with the most valuable items to maximize the total value while staying within the weight limit.